# how to do a comparison in if statement .sh shell

Tags: shell

I have a string that is getting stored in a variable.

```
a = "testing123"
```

Where is output from one of the functions that I will be getting. 
    b = "testing123"
But b could be testing456

As long as b is equal to testing***, it prints out the output

So trying to get the output of the function and compare it with a and see if both matches then bingo.. 
Now all I am trying to do is:

```
if [ "$b" =~ testing "[0-9]*"]
   then echo "yay, finally worked"
fi
```

Error: It is giving me [testing123 instead of testing123

Yes, I do realize I could simple do this:

```
if [ "$a" -eq "testing123" ]
```

But for learning purpose this is good to know :D

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record you didn't tell us what wasn't working about that. That being said, presumably that is failing to match and that's likely because you quoted the "wrong" part of the right-hand side pattern. You want to quote literal text and not quote pattern characters (that being said you don't really need to quote anything there I don't think).

Comment: You tagged this `awk`, but there's no awk in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
a="testing123"
echo "$a" | grep "^testing[0-9][0-9]*$"
if [ $? -eq "0" ]
then
  echo "yay, finally worked"
fi
```

I have added [0-9] twice to ensure the string ends with atleast one number. If you don't want to have atleast one number then use [0-9] only once. Hope this helps!

Comment: What I dont understand is how is $a comparing with testing here

Comment: Well, in this case, echo command prints the value of variable a and then grep command checks if the echoed string matches with regex or not. Its as simple as filtering output like below -> "tail -f server.log | grep RUNNING".

Comment: Sorry for nagging, if [  echo "$a" | grep "^testing[0-9]*$" -eq "0"]
then
echo "yaya, finally worked"
fi

is giving this error:
grep: ^testing[0-9]*$: No such file or directory
grep: 0]: No such file or directory


: [: ']' missing

wonder why

Comment: Well that will not work. The "echo/grep" command is successful when it finds that string but it fails when it doesn't finds that string. Then you check the status of the last command which is returned as 0 in case of success and non-zero in case failure.

Comment: oh.. so I cannot even assign x = echo "a"
           then use if[ "x" | grep..]

Because I even tried this and it failed..

Comment: yeah. or you can save the status of echo/grep command in var like "result=$?" and use that in if-then statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61082/discussion-between-dganesh2002-and-kyle).

Answer (score 4):

You are using wrong square brackets, need to use `[[` and `]]` and remember it works in `BASH` not in `sh` .

Following should work in BASH:

```
b="testing123"
[[ "$b" =~ ^testing[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "matched"
matched
```

Comment: +1. For added emphasis, for variables assignments, you **must not** have spaces around the `=`

Comment: So in .sh it shall be something like:

     
      if ["$b" =~ "^multi_du[0-9]+$"]

Because I used [[]] brackets it gave me error.

Comment: No as I said `=~` operator is not available in `sh`, you need to use `Bash` for this.

Comment: oh how about I use, Since I am doing it in .sh, I don't want to confuse myself more:
["$b" -eq ^testing[0-9]+$]
I think this should work now correct?

Comment: In `sh` you can use: `echo "$b" | grep -Eq '^testing[0-9]+$' && echo "matched"` but cannot use `=~` in `sh`

Comment: I am confused, you are using grep to get output from a file? but there is so file :S

output is in "b" and then just comparing that with testing***.

Comment: I understood what you did what echo "$b" thats makes sense. But for grep, it will look for that in a file so it wont work. I am hard coding the string to be testing***. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You seem to be confused. There is no use of `file` in my suggested `grep` command. This command `echo "$b" | grep -Eq '^testing[0-9]+$' && echo "matched"` is using grep on output of `echo "$b"` command.

Comment: @anubhava, [0-9]+ doesn't seems to work in sh. I posted another solution

Comment: So what you means here is that if value of b is equal to value of "testing123" it is matched correct?

Comment: Yes thats how you add pipe and grep to trim your output, isn't it?

Comment: yes but y echo ? I shall be able to use "$a" directly?

Comment: @kyle `grep` reads either from standard input or a named file. `$a | grep ...` would try to run a command whose name is stored in the variable `a`; the `echo` is the command which writes its argument to standard output, and so via the pipe to `grep`'s standard input.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell does not support regular expression matching directly via the `=~` operator or something similar, you can use the `expr` command as a lightweight alternative to using `grep`.

```
if expr "$a" : "testing[0-9]*$" > /dev/null; then
    echo "yay, finally worked"
fi
```

Note that `expr` assumes the regex will be matched against the beginning of the string (as if it began with `^`). If you want to the regex to match starting anyway, you'll need to prefix your regex with `.*` to successfully match anything before the start of your pattern.